# How will you describe ontology of God?

Tags: ontology

I am trying to understand ontology. Suppose God exists then how will you describe the ontology of God?

(Several texts have been written in praise of God ,Allah etc … Those books gives some credence to the theory that God exists. And definitely there have been practical consequences of believing in God.)

Comment: The ontology of God is the study of the essence of God, of his/her characteristic properties, and of his existence. For the Indic context I propose the Nyaya sutra 4.1.19-4.1.21. For the Christian context Thomas Aquinas, Summa Theologiae I, Questio 2ff, https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Summa_Theologiae/First_Part#Treatise_on_the_One_God_(Questions_2-26)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you start by the assumption that God exists, then you are talking about theology; theology studies the nature of God.

On the other hand ontology is the study of being: what "things" exist and how they are related to each other. Ontology is basically a framework of thought. Everyone has his own kind of ontology.

From the moment you start to think what exists, you are in ontology. And eventually one way or another you come across the concept of God.

I haven't step into any philosopher starting from ancient Greece that has not dealt with the concept of God in one way or another.

I suspect that what you are searching for is the [ontological argument](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ontological_argument#:%7E:text=An%20ontological%20argument%20is%20a,state%20of%20being%20or%20existing.).

I hope you will find it convincing.